# Ruby on Rails - Get parent attribute from child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby app I have two classes Event and Company, such that Event...

```
belongs_to :company
```

Then in event.jst.eco I have the following code...

```
 <span><%= @event.get'company_id'=></span>
```

However instead of returning the company_id I want to return the company name which is an attribute of the parent class Company.

I would have thought it was something like...

```
<%= @event.company.get('name') %>
```

but that just gives me...

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Site#index
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `@event.company.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write as :-

```
<span><%= @event.company.name =></span>
```

As per the [`belongs_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to) association inside the `Event` model, it must have a method called `#company`, which will give you the associated `Company` object.